# Problem with reading array of objects from file

Tags: java, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

i have a class `writeStudent` like this:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Objects.Student;
import ultils.Ultil;

/**
 *
 * @author Duongdnse151384
 */
public class WriteStudent {

    public static <E> ArrayList<E> getFile(ArrayList<E> list, String filename){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename + ".txt");
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
                Object obj = ois.readObject();
                list = (ArrayList<E>) obj;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static <E> boolean setFile(ArrayList<E> list, String filename){
        boolean check = false;
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename+".txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        
            oos.writeObject(list);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            check = true;
        
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return check;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           ArrayList<Student> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
           inputList = getFile(inputList, "student");
           ArrayList<Student> studentList = inputList;
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE15000", "Hoa Doan") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE140987", "Duyhnq") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE150820", "Hyln") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151087", "Thinhdnp") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151129", "Trieudh") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151384", "DuongDN") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151391", "Phatht") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151418", "Kietdt") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151422", "Hoangtm") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE151438", "Quannh") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE160026", "Kiennt") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE160037", "Thanhpt") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE160111", "Thinhnpp") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE160186", "Duynd") {
//             });
//             studentList.add(new Student("SE160865", "Nhatlm") {
//             });
           System.out.println(studentList);
//             studentList.removeAll(studentList);
//            if(setFile(studentList, "student")) System.out.println("success");
            
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
```

I can write data to file `student.txt` by using `setFile` method. But when I try to read `student.txt` with `getFile` method, the output has an error:

```
run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.WriteStudent$1
[]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I found that inside `student.txt` is a part like `test.WriteStudent$1`, full of `student.txt` below:

```
¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   sr test.WriteStudent$1„ÍÉæo_ZÙ  xr Objects.StudentÄ‰õ
:¼| L     STUDENTIDt Ljava/lang/String;L studentNameq ~ xpt SE15000t Hoa Doansr test.WriteStudent$2,kU­©¨-  xq ~ t SE140987t Duyhnqsr test.WriteStudent$3CØ\æ`ë"[  xq ~ t SE150820t Hylnsr test.WriteStudent$4RG!0÷ s  xq ~ t SE151087t Thinhdnpsr test.WriteStudent$5]E‰rÕ4Q  xq ~ t SE151129t Trieudhsr test.WriteStudent$6çMdwe
  xq ~ t SE151384t DuongDNsr test.WriteStudent$7ù²Ëª´P  xq ~ t SE151391t Phathtsr test.WriteStudent$8ûä[KgFg$  xq ~ t SE151418t Kietdtsr test.WriteStudent$9=Ñ*°+i%  xq ~ t SE151422t Hoangtmsr test.WriteStudent$10^™^ÓÇyäš  xq ~ t SE151438t Quannhsr test.WriteStudent$11Br~‰Â>A  xq ~ t SE160026t Kienntsr test.WriteStudent$12;þ©"!´¬*  xq ~ t SE160037t Thanhptsr test.WriteStudent$13ôXã€€h$  xq ~ t SE160111t Thinhnppsr test.WriteStudent$14¯ÆiŠ-   xq ~ t SE160186t Duyndsr test.WriteStudent$15'2T ZÊ  xq ~ t SE160865t Nhatlmx
```

I know something wrong in this but I have no idea how to fix it. can somebody help me, please?
p/s: I have tested with `ArrayList<String>`:

```
        ArrayList<String> i = new ArrayList<String>();
        i = getFile(i, "i");
        System.out.println(i);
        i.add("test");
        if(setFile(i, "i")) System.out.println("Success!");
```

And it works completely, now I don't know how I wrong...

---

Answer (score 0):

If file have extension .txt - probably you want to save plain text.
Now you save serialized objects from your list beacuse you are using ObjectOutputStream.

If each element on your list is a line then just save each line using FileOutputStream, reference: https://zetcode.com/java/fileoutputstream/

All what you need is to remove ObjectOutputStream , then .getBytes() for each line from list, and execute .write() on your FileOutputStream object.

Comment: this is a mini version of my project, I saved to `.txt` file because its easy to ro read what inside by `notepad`. In my main project, I use `.dat` with some encode. But It has the same issue.